# Bootstrap 5 carousel with collapse on slide event

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap 5 carousel with collapse outside the carousel going but I'm stuck on the java script part. I am a absolute beginner and not sure how to solve this problem.

I made a console log to see if I have the carousel slides and yes this is working. I can get the collapse working. because of "SyntaxError: Document.querySelector: '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector".

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
  document.getElementById("carouselExampleControls");
  document.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function (e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
  });


  document.getElementById("carouselExampleControls");
  document.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function (e) {
    var forSlide = document.querySelector(
      ".for-slide-" + document.querySelector(e.relatedTarget).index()
    );
    if (!forSlide.classList.contains("in")) {
      document.querySelector("#collapseGroup>.collapse.in").collapse("hide");
      forSlide.collapse("show");
    }
  });
```

```css
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
.img0 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.img1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
.img2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.img3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}
.description-group {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.textarea {
  margin: 20px 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row row-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img0" alt="Slide 0">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 0</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img1" alt="Slide 1">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 1</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img2" alt="Slide 2">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 2</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img3" alt="Slide 3">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 3</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 description-group">
      <div id="collapseGroup">
        <div class="collapse for-slide-0 in">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 0</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-1">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slides 1</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-2">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 2</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-3">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 3</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to refer to the correct slide from carousel item. You can get index of current `targetElement` node using `indexOf`. However the collapse part still doesn't work need to fix the markup.

```js
document.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  var child = e.relatedTarget
  var index = [].indexOf.call(child.parentNode.children, child);

  var forSlide = document.querySelector(".for-slide-" + index);
  
  console.log("should show collapse " + forSlide.innerText.trim())
  return;
  
  // check your collapse code currently doesn't work 
  
  if (!forSlide.classList.contains("in")) {
    document.querySelector("#collapseGroup>.collapse.show").collapse("hide");
    forSlide.collapse("show");
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
.img0 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.img2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.img3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.description-group {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.textarea {
  margin: 20px 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row row-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></a>
          <a type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img0" alt="Slide 0">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 0</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img1" alt="Slide 1">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 1</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img2" alt="Slide 2">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 2</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img3" alt="Slide 3">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Caption 3</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 description-group">
      <div id="collapseGroup">
        <div class="collapse for-slide-0 show in">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 0</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-1">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slides 1</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-2">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 2</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse for-slide-3">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="textarea">
              <h3>Text for Slide 3</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Goldman for the correction.

Comment: i am not able to solve this: if (!forSlide.classList.contains("in")) {
    document.querySelector("#collapseGroup>.collapse.show").collapse("hide");
    forSlide.collapse("show");